# A word for a rule that isn't strictly enforced since proper enforcement would result in the expulsion/paralysis of too many members?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a rule that is not strictly enforced since proper enforcement of that rule would result in the expulsion/paralysis of too many members?

E.g., In "Game of Thrones" there is a part where a character says something to the effect of "If we beheaded all the watchmen who go to Molestown we'd only have ghosts manning the wall.".

Comment: There's the line from _Hamlet_ that's made it into everyday English: _a custom more honour'd in the breach than the observance_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One term is *dead letter.*

> A law or treaty which has not been repealed but is ineffectual or defunct in practice.
>
> > *‘Environmental law, just like any other, is a dead letter if not enforced.’*
>
> [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dead_letter)

OED has the term first used with this meaning in 1663 following an earlier more literal meaning, "A writing, etc. taken in a bare literal sense without reference to its ‘spirit’, and hence useless or ineffective."

It's likely that *letter* here means much the same as *letter* in *letter of the law,* rather than "item of mail."

Answer (score 0):

a **loosely** enforced rule is:  [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/loosely)

made less strict; relaxed:

Thus:

> The rule is **loosely** enforced, as proper enforcement would result
>   in the expulsion/paralysis of too many members?